# HttpClient with NetworkCredential returns 401 for .net core 200 for .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have this code:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

            using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential })
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    string authUrl = "https://example.net";
                    var authresponse = client.GetAsync(authUrl).Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

(url and credentials are anonymized)

In .net framework console I get response 200.

In .net core 1.1 I get response 401.

I guess it is difference in implementation between .net core and .net framework. Any ideas how to solve this? Or where to report this bug/feature?

Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Stepped through and inspected everything in each environment? There could be pieces there that aren't getting populated.

Comment: @krillgar yes I did, the classes are different so it is hard to tell. I did also inspect requests in Fiddler. And nothing obvious..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I solved it like this:

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

using (WinHttpHandler handler = new WinHttpHandler() { ServerCredentials = credential})
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        string authUrl = "https://example.net";
        var authresponse = client.GetAsync(authUrl).Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use a CredentialCache explicitly specifying that you're using NTML scheme. Also apparently this should not be necessary in more recent .netcore versions

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9533